# if freemarker could add extends feature?

Tags: freemarker

some directive：

```
#extends, #block, #override, #super
```

for example, I have a layout template file,

base.ftl

```
<html>  
    <head>  
        <#block name="head">base_head_content</#block>  

    </head>  
    <body>  
        <#block name="body">base_body_content</#block>  

    </body>  
</html>
```

now, I write my page,

child.ftl

```
<@override name="body">  
    <div class='content'>  

        Powered By rapid-framework  
    </div>
    <@super/>  
</@override>  
<@extends name="base.ftl"/>
```

Then, I have the following outputs,

```
<html>  
    <head>  
        base_head_content  
    </head>  

    <body>  
        <div class='content'>  

            Powered By rapid-framework  
        </div> 
        base_body_content 
    </body>  

</html>
```

Isn't it a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this this a question, or a request? I mean, StackOverflow is not a good place to do the last.

That FreeMarker doesn't support this kind of thing (unless you hack it together from custom directives, which is possible to an extent) is a well known problem. The only reason it doesn't support something like this (yet...) is simply the lack of development time.

Comment: the GitHub Repository could open the issues.

Comment: And well, I can maybe develop this feature and send a pull-request

Comment: Frankly, I think it's very difficult to do this in a way so that it can be part of the template language. There was a lot of discussion about the topic in the past and people expect different things from a feature like this. Writing some custom directives for it and then publish that as an FTL library is more realistic. (Of course, unless you are *really* serious about this.) It's also a good first round to explore what's needed.

Comment: Thanks, I should first attempt to develop this feature as a library. Then, see everyone's opinions.